# How to get css pseudo-element content with python selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P0VT.png)

How could I locate the pseudo element using selenium?
My desired output is the address "http: //www.meishij.net/alldish.php?id=1799616".

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please edit your post and inline the image by placing a `!` (exclamation mark) before the image link/tag. Please also provide some context which pseudo element you mean and _why_ you want to select that? What do you want to test on that element?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pages = requests.get('http://www.meishij.net/zuofa/qingjiaosansi.html')
soup =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find('a',{'title':"青椒三丝"}).get('href')
print(result)
```

`result` will be:

```
http://www.meishij.net/alldish.php?id=1799616
```